# Should a Geforce GT620 get this hot while running browser games?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, itunes, gpu

We have a desktop with a Geforce GT620 connected via VGA cable to a single screen. When running simple browser games or using itunes to view films the GPU goes up to a temperature of around 75-88 degrees C and the fan gets very noisy. Any idea what may be causing this? The machine is about 1 year old.

Comment: How dirty is it? After one year it probably require cleaning the fans and heatsinks. BTW, use DVI/HDMI/DP if possible, VGA is bad.

Comment: It does look a bit dusty on the outside, I'll try and give it a clean and see if that helps, it belongs to my in-laws so I can't try it for a week or so. Any other ideas if that doesn't help?